# Checking if the cell values in a dataframe are strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
ID   Image   
a    None
b    ushfkf.jpg
c    ihfskjd.jpg
d    None
```

The .jpg's values are of string type. I want to check whether the row contains an Image. I tried:

```
df['hasimage'] = np.where(df['Image']==None, True, False)
```

But I only get an extra column of `False`s. How can I simply check if the cell has a string in it, without complicating it with None?

Comment: `df['hasimage'] = df['Image'].astype(str).str.endswith('.jpg')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are `None` like `Nonetype`s:

If testing not `NaN` or `None`s use [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": list("abcd"), "Image": [None, "ushfkf.jpg", "ihfskjd.jpg",None]})

df['hasimage1'] = df['Image'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))
df['hasimage2'] = df['Image'].notna()

print (df)
  ID        Image  hasimage1  hasimage2
0  a         None      False      False
1  b   ushfkf.jpg       True       True
2  c  ihfskjd.jpg       True       True
3  d         None      False      False
```

EDIT:

If `None`s are strings:

Test by [`Series.str.endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": list("abcd"), "Image": ["None", "ushfkf.jpg", "ihfskjd.jpg","None"]})

df['hasimage1'] = df['Image'] != 'None'
df["hasimage2"] = df["Image"].str.endswith(".jpg", na=False)

print (df)
  ID        Image  hasimage1  hasimage2
0  a         None      False      False
1  b   ushfkf.jpg       True       True
2  c  ihfskjd.jpg       True       True
3  d         None      False      False
```

Comment: I get Falses all the way again. I checked the type and it is string, though.

Comment: @johnnydoe - It means all values are strings, added `EDIT` part of my answer.

Comment: Now I get all Trues. I checked the type for each cell and if it's an image name it's String, and if it's None it's NoneType. I really can't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: @johnnydoe - What is `print (df['Image'].head(10).tolist())` ? Do you test all solution and nothig working?

Comment: @johnnydoe - Added sample data to answer.

Comment: It is [None, 'ushfkf.jpg', 'ihfskjd.jpg', None, None, None, 'fhjs.png', 'shfj.JPG', None, None]

Comment: @johnnydoe - So first part not working? `df['hasimage1'] = df['Image'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))
df['hasimage2'] = df['Image'].notna()` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the string contains `.jpg`.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": list("abcd"), "Image": [None, "ushfkf.png", "ihfskjd.jpg","None"]})
df["hasimage"] = df["Image"].str.contains(".png|.jpg", na=False)
df
```

Comment: This works, but I get a column of True, False and None's. It's also complicated if the extension of the image can also be .png, for example.

Comment: I updated my answer to (i) ensure that None (if not of type str) receives false and (ii) to also handle other file extensions. Regarding (ii): you can simply use "|" to check for different file extensions.